# RESTKit serializing nil to JSON

Tags: iphone, json, serialization, restkit, afnetworking

I'm new to RESTKit 0.20, but I was wondering, is it possible as of right now to serialize an object's nil instance variable to JSON?

To be precise, I want to serialize NSString that is nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is added in a recent (at time of writing) commit: [bb34247aef19d40b725bdcc8e96466f80a033124](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/commit/bb34247aef19d40b725bdcc8e96466f80a033124). So it requires you to use at least v0.22.0

The linked commit includes a number of new tests which show the mapping in action.

Comment: Thank you wain, i just installed mine last week, don't know the exact version right now